# Cannot get v-if to correctly show list items based on property type

Tags: list, vue.js, render

I'm not sure why my v-if is not working. I'm trying to show a list, if the property is of type 1. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="demo" v-cloak>
  <h1>{{title | uppercase}}</h1>
  <p v-if="todo.type === '1'">Showing type: 1</p>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="todo in todos" :class="{ done: todo.done }" @click="todo.done = !todo.done">
      {{ todo.value }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    title: 'todos',
    todos: [{
      type: '1',
      value: 'Code'
    }, {
      type: '2',
      value: 'Debug'
    }] //testing with data use: [{done:false,content:'testing'}]
  }
})
```

**Jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/syed263/yMv7y/7972/

Comment: Because "todo.type"  does not really exist in your data object.   It is not created until you begin to iterate your todos object in the v-for loop and you have your conditional outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you for that, this fixed the issue, although I still have an empty list item: http://jsfiddle.net/syed263/yMv7y/7979/

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above you need to start your v-for loop in a parent element.  Something like this.

```
<div id="demo" v-cloak>
 <h1>{{title | uppercase}}</h1>
 <span v-for="todo in todos">
   <p v-if="todo.type === '1'">Showing type: 1</p>
   <p v-if="todo.type === '2'">Showing type: 2</p>
     <ul>
       <li  v-if="todo.type === '1'" :class="{ done: todo.done }"    @click="todo.done = !todo.done">
    {{ todo.value }}
      </li>
     <li  v-if="todo.type === '2'" :class="{ done: todo.done }" @click="todo.done = !todo.done">
    {{ todo.value }}
     </li>
    </ul>
 </span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skribe/yMv7y/7982/

Answer (score -1):

Your statement `<p v-if="todo.type === '1'">Showing type: 1</p>` is outside the loop. So the `todo` is undefined here.

You should try something like this :

```
<div id="demo" v-cloak>
  <h1>{{title | uppercase}}</h1>
  <p>Showing type: 1</p>
  <div v-for="todo in todos" v-if="todo.type === '1'">
    <ul>
      <li :class="{ done: todo.done }" @click="todo.done = !todo.done">
        {{ todo.value }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/7986/).